# if(newIssueproject.getVersions().contains(v)) always returns false although it should be true

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am trying to create a new version only if a specific project has the same versions of the current issue. Here it is made in the following code block:

```
for( Version v: issue.getFixVersions()){

                        if(newIssueproject.getVersions().contains(v)){

                                 Version mynewVersion= ComponentAccessor.versionManager.createVersion(v.getName()+"-Inbox", startDate, releaseDate, description, newIssueproject.id, scheduleAfterVersion, released)

                                 mynewVersions.add(mynewVersion)

                        }
```

The problem is that               `if(newIssueproject.getVersions().contains(v))` always returns false although it should be true sometimes. As a result, I always have versions that are null. So how can this be fixed?

```
def issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager()

def authenticationContext = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext

def issueFactory = ComponentAccessor.getIssueFactory()

def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()

def userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserUtil()

 def currentUserObj = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser();

long issueLinkType= 10070 as long

long sequence =1 as long

long newissueTypeID= 19 as long

long myissueID= issue.getId() as long

// the key of the project under which the version will get created

 final String projectKey = "SF"

// the start date - optional

final Date startDate = null

// the release date - optional

final Date releaseDate = null

// a description for the new version - optional

final String description = null

// id of the version to schedule after the given version object - optional

final Long scheduleAfterVersion = null

// true if this is a released version

final boolean released = false

def project = ComponentAccessor.projectManager.getProjectObjByKey(projectKey)

assert project : "Could not find project with key $projectKey"

def projectComponentManager = ComponentAccessor.getProjectComponentManager()

         int counter=0

        for(ProjectComponent component: componentList){

                    MutableIssue newissue= ComponentAccessor.issueFactory.getIssue()

                                        //set values

                    newissue.setProjectObject(issue.projectObject)

                    newissue.setIssueTypeId("19") 

                    newissue.setSummary("MOUNA CAMELIA")

                    newissue.setDescription("MOUNA CAMELIA")

                    newissue.reporter = issue.getReporter()

                    String componentName= component.getName()

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 5 "+component)

                    def shortenedComponentName = componentName.substring(componentName.indexOf("-")+1) 

                    def projectName = componentName.substring(0, componentName.indexOf("-")) 

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 6 projectName--"+projectName+"--" )

                    def newIssueproject = ComponentAccessor.projectManager.getProjectObjByKey(projectName)

                    newissue.setProjectObject(newIssueproject)

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA ISSUE GET VERSIONS "+newIssueproject.getVersions()+"-========= "+issue.getFixVersions())

                    def mynewVersions = new ArrayList <Version> ()

                    for( Version v: issue.getFixVersions()){

                        if(newIssueproject.getVersions().contains(v)){

                                 Version mynewVersion= ComponentAccessor.versionManager.createVersion(v.getName()+"-Inbox", startDate, releaseDate, description, newIssueproject.id, scheduleAfterVersion, released)

                                 mynewVersions.add(mynewVersion)

                        }

                

                    }

                    newissue.setFixVersions(mynewVersions)
```

Comment: As always, impossible to know for sure, but it could be that `Version` does not have an `equals` method 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to javadoc looks versions are comparable by ID or by NAME

https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.6.1/com/atlassian/jira/project/version/Version.html

> Field Summary: NAME_COMPARATOR, ID_COMPARATOR

your code could look like this if you want to compare by version name:

```
def matchedVersions = issue.getFixVersions().intersect(
        newIssueproject.getVersions(), 
        Version.NAME_COMPARATOR 
    )
```

Comment: it's not working, it's always returning an empty list even though it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: i don't see lists and it's values. only can say - if you see result empty then the values not matching...

Comment: no they are I have printed the two lists and there are some common elements

Comment: could you provide the following outputs: `println issue.getFixVersions()[0].getClass()`, `println newIssueproject.getVersions()[0].getClass()`

Comment: ISSUE FIX VERSIONS class com.atlassian.jira.project.version.VersionImpl===> Output for  issue.getFixVersions()[0].getClass()

Comment: NEW ISSUE PROJECT VERSIONS class com.atlassian.jira.project.version.VersionImpl ====> Output for newIssueproject.getVersions()[0].getClass()

Comment: it works, I tried it again